# Is there an equivalent of /etc/sysconfig/servicename for Solaris?

Tags: solaris, solaris-10

On Debian and RedHat machines there is an `/etc/default/servicename` or `/etc/sysconfig/servicename` file that is loaded before init scripts are run.

Is there an equivalent for Solaris?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solaris 10 and 11 use what's called the Service Management Facility (SMF).  The equivalents to Linux `/etc/default/servicename` and `/etc/sysconfig/servicename` would be found somewhere in the SMF's data.

An overview for Solaris 11 is available:

[**Introducing the Basics of Service Management Facility (SMF) on Oracle Solaris 11**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/intro-smf-basics-s11-1729181.html)

> The Service Management Facility (SMF), first introduced in Oracle
>   Solaris 10, is a feature of the operating system for managing system
>   and application services, replacing the legacy `init` scripting
>   start-up mechanism common to prior releases of Oracle Solaris and
>   other UNIX operating systems. SMF improves the availability of a
>   system by ensuring that essential system and application services run
>   continuously even in the event of hardware or software failures. SMF
>   is one of the components of the wider Oracle Solaris Predictive Self
>   Healing capability.
>
> This article gives an introduction to SMF and demonstrates some simple
>   examples of administering services on Oracle Solaris 11. More advanced
>   administration topics will be covered in another article. To learn
>   more about SMF, check out a variety of content at the [SMF technology
>   page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/technologies/smf-1690889.html) on Oracle Technology Network.
>
> ...

If you're familiar with legacy `init` scripts in the `/etc/rc?.d` directories, this tutorial on how to migrate such legacy scripts into SMF-based services is probably a good place to learn where the parts of SMF are actually located:

**[How to Migrate Control of System Services from Scripts to the Service Management Facility](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/scripts-to-smf-1641705.html)**

In general, you can start by looking under `/lib/svc` and `/var/svc`.